# How to color function outputs that come from JS into the EJS

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am very new to coding, have been learning for the last 5 months :)

In the web application I am trying to develop; I have a main page - index.html. In here, end user enters some values and then submits the form.

When values reach to backend, some functions run in index.js and then results go into middleware and then rendered into views/index.ejs and goes to a table which is displayed to end user.

My question is how do I show the function outputs in different colors from JS which are shown via EJS?

A Sample function code in my index.js:

```js
function calculateFinalH1Value(Dist) {
  const finalH1Values = ["1", "1", "1"]; // in the rendered EJS page, finalH1Values[0] should show in red color finalH1Values[1] in blue color.

  for (let i = 0; i < finalH1Values.length; i++) {
    const h1 = Dist;

    if (h1 <= 2) {
      return finalH1Values[0];
    } else if (h1 <= 6) {
      return finalH1Values[1];
    } else if (h1 <= 12) {
      return finalH1Values[2];
    } else {
      return "-";
    }
  }
}

var finalH1SunMoon = calculateFinalH1Value(DistSunMoon);
var finalH1SunMercury = calculateFinalH1Value(DistSunMercury);
var finalH1SunVenus = calculateFinalH1Value(DistSunVenus);
var finalH1SunMars = calculateFinalH1Value(DistSunMars);
```

My sample EJS code is as below:

```ejs
   <tr>
        <th scope="row" style="border: 1px solid grey;">1</th>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;">Sun Moon</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;"><%= finalH1SunMoon %></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;" ><%=finalH1SunMercury%></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;"><%=finalH1SunVenus%></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid grey;"><%=finalH1SunMars%></td>

    </tr>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you mean like `<span style="color:red"><%= someValue %></span>`?